# Classifying range of symbology classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, legend

I want to create several dozen maps where all have a field with a range from 0 to 100.

I need to classify these into symbology classes every 15 and make a legend out of this.

However, the map I am currently using only has values from 55-100, and the others will certainly have a different range (maybe from 20-95 as an example).

I tried creating manual classes but when typing "15,30, and 45  it reverts these break values to the lowest number in the current shapefile, which is 55.

However I still need to create a legend showing all these classifications and it needs to show what color a score of 15 would be even if there is not one in the map.

[image: Manual Classification]

[image: Symbology Classes]

Comment: Merge 2-3 feature classes with extreme values and use it as layout.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem in 10.6. I can set breaks that don't exist in my data. What did you do exactly?

Comment: Reclassifying your data with new data field would be much helpful to you.

Comment: I right clicked on the layer, went to symbology settings, opened the quantities option for symbology, clicked "Classify..." and then changed the breaks to manual. I then tried to change them to be below 55 and it wouldn't accept these changes and would revert all those numbers below 55 to be exactly 55

Comment: If your just using it for a legend; why not just create a shape with a low value of 0 and high value of 100? Then, you can turn the new layer off and add it to the legend - make sure it displays in the legend while off with the legend settings - and design the legend values with that layer.

Comment: Yes see the accepted answer here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108156/manually-classifying-graduated-data-outside-of-range-in-arcgis-for-desktop?rq=1